# C# Tell my interface it is only going to be implemented by struct

Tags: c#, class, parsing, struct, interface

I am trying to implement an **IParseable** interface to simplify configuration reading:

```
public interface IParseable {
    IParseable Parse(string From);
}
```

To parse a string I've built these string extension methods:

```
public static T ToIParseableStruct<T>(this string Me) where T : struct, IParseable
    => Parser.IParseableStructFromString<T>(Me); //Never returns null

public static T ToIParseableClass<T>(this string Me) where T : class, IParseable, new()
    => Parser.IParseableClassFromString<T>(Me); //Could return null
```

These are the implementations:
*(Inside an internal static Parser class)*

```
/// <exception cref="FormatException">Thrown when <paramref name="Value"/> could not be parsed. (See <see cref="IParseable.Parse(string)"/>)</exception>
public static T IParseableStructFromString<T>(string Value) where T : struct, IParseable {
    T result = new T();
    try {
        return (T)result.Parse(Value);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return ThrowFormatException<T>(Value, ex); //Ignore this
    }
}

/// <exception cref="FormatException">Thrown when <paramref name="Value"/> could not be parsed. (See <see cref="IParseable.Parse(string)"/>)</exception>
public static T IParseableClassFromString<T>(string Value) where T : class, IParseable, new() {
    T result = new T();
    try {
        return (T)result.Parse(Value);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return ThrowFormatException<T>(Value, ex); //Ignore this
    }
}
```

So far so great!
I also wanted to allow to parse a string to a nullable struct.
This is what I tried:

```
public interface IParseableStructNullable {
    IParseableStructNullable? Parse(string From);
}
```

Unfortunately the generic T parameter of a Nullable must be a struct.
And because my interface doesn't know it is going to be implemented by a struct I cannot `return IParseableStructNullable?`.

Do you know any solution to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `IParseable` generic:

```
public interface IParseable<T> {
    T Parse(string from);
}
```

then you could do the same for `IParseableNullableStruct` and add a `struct` constaint:

```
public interface IParseableStruct<T> where T : struct {
    T? Parse(string from);
}
```

Comment: The moment you realize how simple it could be... Thank you Lee :)